# RAID1 superblock recovery

Tags: mdadm

I have a big issue with my RAID1 array.

I transferred my RAID1 (mdadm) to a new PC, but when I was installing it, I rebuilt the array as a RAID0. No data has been written to the disks.

When I try to reassemble as a RAID1 I get the error:

> /dev/sdc has no superblock.

I am struggling with this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't understand your setup. What disks did you use? Did you transfer both disks into the new PC? What commands did you use to rebuild the RAID? Why did you even *rebuild* the RAID instead of just plugging in the two disks: did you transfer a single disk and if so what did you do to prepare the other disk?

Comment: everything was done without thinking. 
i installed both disks from the old pc into the new pc and used webmin to setup the array, but instead of telling webmin that the array was RAID1 i told it that it was RAID0.

Comment: So you didn't rebuild the array, you created a new array on the same space. I'm not familiar enough with the array layout to know what you've overwritten but you've probably lost data. I'd just restore the whole thing from a backup at this stage.